# How to Use MKMapViewDelegate Methods in MVVM Model

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, mapkit

In my view controller, there is an outlet to a `MKMapView` and the view controller naturally conforms to `MKMapViewDelegate` to perform MapKit operations.

I'm trying to migrate to the MVVM model before further progress in the project in order to keep it tidy. However, I'm drawing a blank about how to move all the `MKMapViewDelegate` methods to another file where the `MKMapView` outlet sits in the view controller.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm coding with Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a situation just like that, when I create a GMSMapViewDelegate separate from my view controller.

What I did and you could try:

- Create a class that extends NSObject and the MKMapViewDelegate. (The delegate needs to conform to NSObjectProtocol)
- You need to create and setup the mapView in the new class, but let the view controller access it.
- **ATTENTION** - remember to maintain a reference to your new class in the view controller. The delegate is a weak variable in the map view.

**MapModelView.swift**

```
class MapModelView:NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

   let mapView:MKMapView!

   init(screenSize: CGRect) {
        // generate the map view at the size of the screen
        // otherwise it won't be seen
        self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
        super.init()
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    } 
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Get the screen size for the map view creation
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        mapKitOperationsDelegate = MapKitOperations(screenSize: screenSize)
        mapView = mapKitOperationsDelegate.getMapView()
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
```

*(Added 02/08/2018)*

**PS**

As mentioned by Chanchal Raj "MapView is a UI component, it shouldn't be in ViewModel class". It was my solution at the time but it's not the correct way, conceptualy speaking (using MVVM).

Comment: Although that weak reference seems dangerous and should be handled carefully that actually makes sense. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to find a better solution, I did not enjoy the NSObject in there.

Comment: Curious about what you'll come up with but shouldn't we subclass NSObject? Isn't that mandatory?

Comment: How should I set the delegate of the map view exactly?

Comment: mapView.delegate = self, inside the delegate initialization. Yeah, I guess that subclass NSObject is mandatory.

Comment: I set the delegate to self inside `MapModelView` class. Inside my view controller, the mapView from `MapModelView`is given to the outlet mapView and somehow my delegate functions are not called; hence no MapKit stuff happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats strange. I was having this problem when my mapView was losing the delegate reference, but if you are keeping a strong reference to it in the view controller thats probably not the case. Take a look at my answer, I edited the code, you should be doing something like that.

Comment: I made some edits. The problem was that the map view created wasn't being displayed since it was 0x0. Therefore I initiated it with the screen size. Now all of the delegate functions are being used and the map view is being rendered as I wanted. Your previous edit led me here actually. Thanks pal.

Comment: MapView is a UI component, it shouldn't be in ViewModel class

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in this cases, is to have the ViewController adopt the protocol, because is part of the View layer and have the `ViewModel` handle the logic from the delegate method.

You could use completion blocks or delegates if it's (in the ViewModel) to handle the logic and return it to the `ViewController`.

This is how I handle my UITableView delegates.

Here's something that could help you decide: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/07/why-not-make-the-viewmodel-the-table-views-data-source/